# How do I modify the entire default "try-catch" template in Settings of IDEA?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

I can not find where to the "try-catch" template in Settings of IDEA?

I want to modify the **entire** template not just what is in the `Catch Statement Body` template.

For example, renaming the reference to the exception from `e` to `ex`.

Comment: yeah - the other day I tried to find it too but gave up. probably should report a bug.

Comment: Found one, vote for it if you want this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116670

Answer (score 17):

In my IntelliJ 11.1.3 I find it under `File Templates`. Go to the `Code` tab and then you have the `Catch Statement Body`.

If it isn't there then you have a problem with the EAP (I haven't tested it).

[image]

---

**Edit**

I guess that IntelliJ does not come with a Live Template for try/catch. It is described [here](http://arhipov.blogspot.se/2011/07/whats-cool-in-intellijidea-part-ii-live.html) how you can do it.

Comment: That only defines content of catch block. Basically what I want to do is to rename variable "Exception e" to "Exception ex" in autogenerated code. It's hard for me to aim on single character when I'm debugging it :)

Comment: @ruslan Well then I must have misunderstood your question. I updated with a link that describes how to set up a Live Template for it. It doesn't seem to be a default one.

Comment: LT is bad solution because it will force me to click Ctrl + Alt + T every time IDEA says some method throws exception instead of just clicking Alt + Enter as I do today.

Answer (score 4):

For the later versions the try/catch template can be customized from

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Template -> Code -> Catch Statement Body
```

Once you do this, This is will be enabled on the `File -> Settings` which indeed is your project settings

Answer (score 1):

By default, the try-catch is in "surround with" live templates (if we can call it so), accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on a selection. However, it is not a rocket science to create your own normal live template for this purpose.

Comment: Не rocket science, но на вопрос ответить не смог :) 1) I don't have default try-catch in Live Templates. See schreenshot: http://i50.tinypic.com/nb2czq.jpg. 2) If I create one in LV I'll have to click Ctrl + Alt + T every time IDEA says some method throws exception instead of just clicking Alt + Enter as I do today.

Comment: Sure, I have the same list of the default templates in my IntelliJ instance, but for Ctrl+Alt+T you can see try/try-catch/try-catch-finally templates available just fine. If you create your own template, it doesn't make sense to create it as a "surround with" template - just create a normal one, which expands on <TAB> or whatever keystroke you have assigned it to. For instance I always create one try-catch template some that it expands automatically once I type 'try<TAB>'. I also puzzled me why it isn't in IDEA by default so it might be a good thing to file a feature request.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my original question. I don't want to click Ctrl+Alt+T, select, click TAB. It's 4 step operations versus Alt+Enter I do right now. All I want is to find where it takes default template from. That's it.