# How do I modify exception variable default name at “try-catch” template in Settings of IDEA/Android Studio?

Tags: java, templates, android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to have on generating try-catch block "ex" name of exception, not "e".

Comment: What work have you done to solve the problem yourself? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: The same question without solution [How do I modify the entire default “try-catch” template in Settings of IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219410/how-do-i-modify-the-entire-default-try-catch-template-in-settings-of-idea)

Comment: @ Evgeny, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2019

Go to **File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **File and Code Templates** > **Code tab** > **Catch Statement Declaration** and replace `${EXCEPTION}` by `ex`.

[image: File > Settings... > Editor > File and Code Templates > Code tab > Catch Statement Declaration> C]

Comment: Ok, I would like to set the ${EXCEPTION}'s value somewhere instead.

Answer (score 1):

you have to modify **code template**, Check the intellij documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-and-code-templates.html?origin=old_help).